# Pass two property as binding CONVERTER PARAMETER

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, converters

I need to pass two of the properties of a control as the converter parameter of binding of the third property.
How can I do that?.
i have created a class and pass that class as converter parameter but unfortunately it is not get value.. the threat is below:[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41077119/error-in-creating-an-instance-of-class-in-xaml-and-setting-its-properties)
Note that I need to pass two parameter to the binding converter parameter to be used in convert and vonvert back. I dont need pass multiple values to binding vonverter!

Comment: what you have done so far ?

Comment: pls see edited post

Comment: why the question gets -1? this question is different.

Comment: cause someone down-voted your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IMultiValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) of `System.Windows.Data`. It can use multiple parameters unlike [IValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: More precisely, it converts multiple *values* of a MultiBinding, but still takes a single *parameter*, just like IValueConverter.

Comment: as i need the multiple converter parameter for convert and convert back, i must use convert parameter that does not support binding to use multiple values.!